# Call to a member function getNbr() on array

Tags: php, symfony

i want to select all users in the database that have the role ROLE_USER only but i get this problm when i call the function they say "Call to a member function getNbr() on null" i think bcoz i use Findby() , bcoz i use the same function in another call and it works great look at the code  :

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

     $us = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $locationus = $us->getRepository('AppBundle:Usr')->findBy(
     [ 'roles' => ["ROLE_USER"] ]);
     echo $nb_us = $locationus->getNbr();

      if($authChecker->isGranted(['ROLE_ADMIN']))
      {
        return $this->render('settingAdmin/profiladmin.html.twig' , array(
          'nb_us' => $nb_us,
      ));
      }
```

and this is the  other function in the UserRepository:

```
class UserRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
  public function getNbr() {

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('l')

                        ->select('COUNT(l)')

                        ->getQuery()

                        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getNbr` is method of `UserRepository` class, so it can be called only for this `UserRepository` class instance. This method returns total  users count.

`findBy` returns array of entities (in you case all users with role `ROLE_USER`), not `UserRepository` class instance, so you can't use `getNbr` in context of this variable

If you want to get the length of array of entities (in you case all users with role `ROLE_USER`), just use `count` function:

```
echo $nb_us = count($locationus);

if($authChecker->isGranted(['ROLE_ADMIN']))
      {
        return $this->render('settingAdmin/profiladmin.html.twig' , array(
          'nb_us' => $nb_us, 'locationus' => $locationus
      ));
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be quite many things going on in the code there:

1) `$us->getRepository('AppBundle:Usr')` is probably typoed and should be `$us->getRepository('AppBundle:User')` instead (?) In general it would be safer to use `$us->getRepository(AppBundle\User::class)` so that syntax errors can be caught easier/earlier.

2) You are trying to invoke repository method on array with `$locationus->getNbr()` which is incorrect on multiple accounts (you cannot invoke functions on arrays - and repository methods cannot be invoked from entities either).

3) why is the code using echo?

4) as an additional note (assuming that this is roughly the full intended code), it would make sense to move all the getters & handling inside the if section so that the code will perform better (it doesn't do unnecessary database queries etc when the user doesn't have enough rights to access the view/information).

If I understood the intention correctly, in this case, the second repository function `getNbr` is superfluous here. If that is intending to just calculate the number of instances returned by the first find:

```
 $locationus = $us->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findBy(['roles' => ["ROLE_USER"] ]);
 $nb_us = count($locationus);
```

Or alternatively (if you want to use and *fix* the `getNbr` repository function) then you don't need the first repository getter. This will require some rewriting of the repository function as well though:

```
 $nb_us = $us->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->getNbr("ROLE_USER");
```